# modify alert message of script manager

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is there any way I can modify `"alert('error !')` part of the script manager to include message in the label below? I don't want to use the label for that, just display database error in the pop up window. I tried adding it with `+` but either it doesn't work or the pop up isnt displayed at all. Thanks

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('error !')  ", true);

lblError.Text = "A database error has occured. <br /> <br />" +
          "Message: " + ex.Message;
```

It doesnt like this:

```
<!-- all the links for datetime picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>



     <script>
         $(function() {
             $( "#datetimepicker" ).datetimepicker();

         });

     </script>
```

Comment: **Please do not add the different type of question in the existing question.** See in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22969710/296861) about javascript error in your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a javascript function and call it to change the text of any label you want.
My suggestion is:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", " changeLabel('" + ex.Message + "', '" + lblError.ClientID +"'); alert('error !');   ", true);
```

And the javascript function :

```
function changeLabel(text, id){
    $("#"+id).val(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot add HTML tag in javascript alert message.

### Simple Alert

Make sure you strip out the single quote `'` in **ex.Message**.

```
try
{
    throw new Exception("test");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string message = string.Format("alert('A database error has occured. {0}');", 
       ex.Message.Replace("'", ""));
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), 
        "alert" + UniqueID, message, true);
}
```

### jQuery Dialog

However you can use [jQuery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) if you want to insert HTML.

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <div id="dialog-text"></div>
</div>

try
{
    throw new Exception("This is an error message.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string message = string.Concat("$(function () {$('#dialog').dialog(); " +
        "$('#dialog-text').html('A database error has occured. " +
        "<br /> <br />", ex.Message, "');});");
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(),
        "alert" + UniqueID, message, true);
}
```

Comment: I think you have javascript error in the rest of your code. Look at in [Chrome Browser Console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#using_the_console_api) and make sure there is no javascript error.

Comment: I tested it, it doesn't work because I also use jquery widget datepicker. It doesn't seem to like the piece of code I have there, could you tell me why ? I included it in the edited version

Comment: Did you get any javascript error in console? If so, you need to fix them first. Or create **a brand new ASP.Net application**, and copy and past the above code and test it.

Comment: I don't have any errors. I created a new page and your code works fine. The issue is when I add the datepicker

Comment: There you go! You found the problem. If you have a question regard `jquery.datetimepicker.js`, please create a separate question so that it'll help the others who looks for the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "<script language='javascript'>alert('A database error has occured.\n\n"+ ex.Message +"' );</script>", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{

..

}
catch(Exception ex)
{

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Database error ocurred : "+ ex.Message.ToString()+"')", true);

}
```

Comment: try using `RegisterStartupScript` instead of `RegisterClientScriptBlock`